# How do I dynamically rename my array keys so that the key can be used as a primary key in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm creating the array dynamically using this tool.

http://174.121.67.116/~achadire/aware5/product_options.php?cid=6

The array output looks like this.

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(
    0 => 300,
    3 => 186,
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => 341,
    3 => 186,
  ),
  2 => array(
    0 => 257,
    3 => 186,
  ),
  3 => array(
    0 => 300,
    3 => 360,
  ),
  4 => array(
    0 => 300,
    3 => 187,
  ),
  5 => array(
    0 => 341,
    3 => 360,
  ),
  6 => array(
    0 => 341,
    3 => 187,
  ),
  7 => array(
    0 => 257,
    3 => 360,
  ),
  8 => array(
    0 => 257,
    3 => 187,
  ),
);
```

0 => Array is the product. [0]=>300, [2]=>186 represent a unique product configuration for the given array key. (i.e blue, big.)  (each vale is a id for an attribute.)

So I want to upload the results to products table in MySQL.   Here is my problem:

First, how do I make my array key a unique 7 digit product code.  In other words, how to I reindex my array with a unique 7 digit code so that I never use the same key for an array twice.  I assume this means figuring out the next value in the mysql database and then looping through the array with i++ before pushing to the table.

Second, the same configuration should only be applied to one product.  So if the array key combination already exists it should skip to the next array.

In short how do I turn my array key into a unique 7 digit product code?  Also, when I upload my array how to I skip over values combinations that already exists in the database so I don't have two different product codes with the same configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was inserting a record into my skus table and returning the primary key to an array.  The I reidex my my array with the new key values and load it into my skus_options table.  Here is the code.  Hope it helps someone down the road.

```
// inserts records into skus table and creates an array of skuids.
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO skus (idcodes, dateadded) VALUES ('$cid', '$dateadded')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc) or die(mysql_error());
$sid = mysql_insert_id();
array_push($skuids, $sid);
}
// creates an array using skuid as the array key and inserts the array into the          skus_options table.
$skus = array_combine($skuids, array_values($skus));
foreach ($skus as $key => $options) {
foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
$query = "INSERT INTO skus_options (skus_options.idskus, skus_options.valueid,   skus_options.idcodes, skus_options.dateadded) VALUES ('$key', '$value', '$cid','$dateadded')";
     $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc) or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop figuring out how to generate unique array ids by fetching the next id in records sequence. You will have big troubles with concurrency. Change your ID field to be an autoincrement and let the DBMS handle that.
2. Create a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `color` and `size` attributes of the `products` table. Then, when you insert use an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax, so you will never have a product with the same attributes.

Comment: Okay.  The primary key can be incremental, but that still do not solve my problem.  Each key in the array still has to be unique.  Otherwise I will have two keys with different combinations of values.   for If my first batch of skus has key [1] -> 1,2,3, [2] => 1,2,5 & [3] => 2,3,4 how can I make my second batch of skus [4], [5], [6].   Again the key identifies the product the values determine the dimensions of product.  So if I ad two keys the product will have 6 values even though they are different products.

Comment: @Busilinks I am not following you. Where do you use this array? When you insert products, when you update, when you search? I am asking for the functionality you are trying to achieve with this array.

Comment: The array is different variations of the same product. I am selecting product attributes (size, color, etc.) and generating product skus in an array.  So, [shoe1] => blue, size 12 - [shoe2] => blue, size 13.  Every time I create the array I would like it to use a unique id so I can seperate the skus.  So, if I use key [0] ever time I build an array I would effectively be adding attributes to a product that already exists.  Making the key unique solves the problem.  That's my thinking anyways...

Comment: @Busilinks You want to generate all possible combinations of a product's attributes? Again, tell me the functionality you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Shef, thanks for your help.  I figured it out.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.